# Bottom of a div sticking to the draggable div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to get the the bottom of a div to stick to the top of the vertically draggable div. Second div should resize the first one. With current solution there is a problem when I start dragging the element second time. Ideally the div should continue from the current position and not jump to the top.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunio/pcJg5/4/

`<div class="a"></div>
 <div class="b">drag me</div>`

```
$(function() 
  $('.b').draggable({axis: 'y', containment: [0, 48, 0, 200]});
  $('.b').bind('drag', function (e, ui) {

    var tmp = ui.position.top;  
    $('.a').css('height', tmp); 
    ui.position.top -=  tmp;   

});});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to set your elements to `position:absolute;`
- If you set than your `.b` element to start from top `20px` make sure to use the **same value** (20) inside your `containment: [0, 20, 0, 200],`

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/metaq/4/edit)**

```
.a {
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;           /* 20px height */
    background-color:blue;
}

.b {
    position:absolute;      /* needed to prevent strange margins on drag */
    top:20px;               /* top at 20px */
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px; 
    background-color: red;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

```
$(function() {

    $('.b').draggable({
      axis: 'y',
      containment: [0, 20, 0, 200],
      drag: function( event, ui ) {
        $('.a').height(ui.position.top);
      }
    });

});
```

<sub>To explain `containment` property</sub>

```
containment: [
   // From position coordinates:
   0  , // .left
   20 , // .top
   // To coordinates:
   0  , // .left
   200  // .top
]
```